# Discrete Mathematics - Proof Methods and Strategy

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $P(x)$ is the statement “$x2 +2x = 1$”. If the domain is the set of integers,
what are the truth values of $\forall x P(x)$ and $\exists x  P(x)$?

Comment: In words, what does each statement say?

Comment: Also did you mean $x^2$ or $x2$? I've corrected the [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for you. It helps questions stay at a high standard. You could also try adding some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) since this isn't a homework help site.